# bazaar relative path in branch config file

Tags: relative-path, bazaar

My group is developing code for use internally as well as to be provided to an external (offsite) group.  A baseline version is delivered externally via tar files, but incremental changes (every week or two) are provided with bzr patch files using the "bzr send" command. I've got a bzr repository for development and when a baseline is sent out, we create a reference branch to capture the as-delivered configuration.  When a patch file is generated, the reference branch is used as the target for the send command, then the patch file is sent to the external site.  My problem is this.... The app I'm developing to automate this process checks consistency between the parent and submit branches as shown with the bzr info command.  If the reference branches move due to disk reorganization, the path to the parent will likely not be correct because the branch.conf file uses relative paths to the parent when the branch is created.  Is there a way for bazaar to save the path to the parent branch as an absolute path in the branch.conf file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the path in `branch.conf` to be an absolute path (URL) and Bazaar should happily handle that.

Setting the path can either be done by editing it with your favorite editor, or using the command:

```
bzr config --scope=branch parent_location=URL
```